# Checkout remains 80% blank Magento 2.0.7

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, magento-2.0.7

If already asked, i'm sorry. I was only able to find this question for Magento 1

I'm working on Magento CE 2.0.7 and my checkout doesn't work (anymore). I also have a problem with login as a customer and then going to checkout. In that situation, it tells me I don't have any products in my cart while the cart on top shows 3 items in the cart.

If I stay as a guest, add a product to my cart and go to checkout i will get the page as shown in the screenshot.

Can anyone tell me if this is a configuration problem or a script problem?

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Update: i noticed that this problem starts when i set some accepted countries. Just to test this, i set The Nederlands, Germany and Belgium to be accepted countries. When i added them all, the checkout worked again. I read something about a bug wich is known by Magento. Isn't there a workaround or other solution know at this point? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a message in the logs (/var/log/$webserver or $magentopath/var/log) ?

Comment: This is not a configuration problem. You'll need to show us some error logs or explain what you did that broke it, since you said it doesn't work *anymore*.

Comment: I'm sorry. Have no logs wich tells me what was going on. Problem is solved for so far but will come back at this if it occurs again, with more information. Thanks anyway :)